# Digital communication management system - Targeting contextually relevant communications (Weatheralpha) - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, rejected, online-advertising, us20120290372

[image]

This Patent Application received a **non-final rejection** by the US Patent Office! An initial rejection is part of the typical course of a patent application.

The rejection was **[based in part on prior art found by Ask Patents community](http://www.scribd.com/doc/188743700/US-20120290372-A1)** below!

---

Thanks to **YOU**, the Ask Patents community, overly-broad claims have at least been narrowed. [Follow @askpatents](https://twitter.com/AskPatents) to block more overly-broad patent applications. **AN OVERBROAD PATENT ON the display of contextually relevant communications based on viewer information and weather information.** - This application from [Weatheralpha, Llc](http://www.weatheralpha.com/) seeks to patent the idea of...dynamically selecting, rotating or altering digital advertisements based on constantly changing weather conditions, thereby allowing advertisers to include weather specific details and improve the contextual accuracy in targeting such advertisements! 10 minutes of your time can help narrow US patent applications before they become patents.  [Follow @askpatents](https://twitter.com/AskPatents) on twitter to help.

**QUESTION** - Have you seen anything that was **published before 10/5/2010** that discusses:

> - Analyzing viewer information and weather information to adjust display of contextually relevant digital communications.

If so, please submit evidence of prior art as an answer to this question. We welcome multiple answers from the same individual.

**EXTRA CREDIT** - **Weather information** pertaining to current, forecasted, or past atmospheric and **environmental conditions** affecting the viewer.

TITLE: **Method of targeting contextually relevant digital communication based on weather conditions**

**Summary**:  [Translated from Legalese into English] Automatically receiving **geolocation information** of a viewer's location, receiving **weather data** relevant to the viewer's location, analysing the **weather data** to identify a **weather condition**, accessing a database multiple available advertisements assigned to the **weather condition**, and selecting a **digital communication** associated with the identified **weather condition** based on the viewer's preference.

- **Publication Number**: [US20120290372A1](http://www.google.com/patents/US20120290372)
- **Application Number**: US 13/555,494
- **Assignee**: Weatheralpha, Llc
- **Prior Art Date**: Seeking prior Art **predating** 10/5/2010
- **Open for Challenge at USPTO:** Open through 5/14/2013
- **Link to Google Prior Art Search** - ["Find Prior Art"](https://www.google.com/patents/related/US20120290372)

**Claim 1** requires each and every step below:

> A computerized method of analyzing weather data to improve the selection of contextually relevant communication, the method comprising:
>
> 1. Receiving passive geolocation information;
> 2. Receiving weather data relevant to the location;
> 3. Analyzing the weather data to identify a weather condition;
> 4. Accessing a database containing a plurality of available advertisements assigned to weather conditions; and
> 5. Selecting a communication associated with the identified weather condition.

In English this means:

> A computerized method of analyzing weather data to improve the selection of contextually relevant communication, the method comprising:
>
> 1. Automatically receiving geolocation information of a viewer's location;
> 2. Receiving weather data relevant to the viewer's location;
> 3. Analyzing the weather data to identify a weather condition;
> 4. Accessing a database containing multiple available advertisements assigned to weather conditions; and
> 5. Selecting a communication associated with the identified weather condition based on a viewer's preference.

Good prior art would be evidence of a system that did each and every one of these steps prior to 10/5/2010

You're probably aware of ten pieces of art that meet this criteria already... separately, the applicant is claiming Weighting weather factor and selecting targeted contextual communications based on rules associated with available digital communication. The selected targeted contextual communications are prioritized based on user preferences.

---

**"The advertisement selection process as determined by current weather events"**

[image]

---

*What is good prior art? Please see our [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).*

*Want to help? Please vote or comment on submissions below. We welcome you to [post your own request for prior art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request+pre-grant) on other questionable US Patent Applications.*

---

Comment: Would the iPhone weather app count as prior art? Detecting where you are and displaying appropriate banners at the top for the current weather conditions. The banners are related to the weather conditions, not some ads, is that relevant for patenting?

Comment: I've seen all of these claims in a plethora of places, but one. It seems to me that the most novel part of these claims is ads based on the weather condition? I.e. if it's raining try selling ponchos, if it's sunny, try selling sun block. But even as is, I'd be surprised if the weather channel wasn't doing this kind of thing already, even 5 years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Official USPTO Prior Art]

This Patent Application received a **non-final rejection** by the US Patent Office! The rejection was **[based in part on prior art found by Ask Patents community](http://www.scribd.com/doc/188743700/US-20120290372-A1)** in this answer!

---

**Method for weather-based advertising**

[US 7080018 B1](https://www.google.com/patents/US7080018)

priority date is May 10, 1999

> ABSTRACT
>   A system and method that allows for weather-based planning of future activities and/or events, and the like. The system includes weather forecast, weather history, activities, advertisement and external information source databases. Also included in the system is a central processing planning server that is accessible via a plurality of internal and external workstations. The workstations provide a graphical user interface for users to enter a series of inputs and receive information (i.e., output) concerning weather-based information. The method involves collecting the series of inputs—geographic location(s), time period(s), and preferred weather pattern(s)—affecting a future event.

One element of claim 1 mentions advertising:

> 6) searching an **advertisement database** for a record having field that match said **geographic location, said activity and said weather condition**; (7) displaying information indicative of said weather condition and an advertisement associated with said record.

Comment: George, In her rejection of this application, the UPTO Examiner cited [US 20020133385 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20020133385) which appears to be a family member of your reference [US 7080018 B1](https://www.google.com/patents/US7080018) based on overlapping inventors and continuity data. So, while the Examiner probably discovered the reference independently from you (based on timing of the office action), I'm accepting the answer for credit here. [Belts and Suspenders](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/belt_and_suspenders) works for us!

Comment: thanks - I don't put much focus on the prior art requests but it is nice to see I *almost* helped in this case.